# Increase voltage level to frequency meter

Tags: frequency, meter

I have a frequency meter that requires a minimum signal voltage of 10VDC to read the frequency.  My output level is only about 2.5-3VDC.  What is the easiest way I can amplify my signal voltage to something over say 12-15 VDC?
Using a TruMeter "APM-FREQ-APO". Measuring around 64HZ.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which meter is it? What frequencies are you going to measure? The answer will be completely different if you need 1 Hz or 1 GHz.

Comment: I am using a TRUMETER "APM-FREQ-APO".  I am measuring around 64 hz.  I am using the meter to tune a circuit in a test box.

Comment: *I am using a TRUMETER "APM-FREQ-APO". I am measuring around 64 hz* That's what is says in the question already. No need to **repeat yourself**. Also: add **new** information into the question (use: Edit), not in a comment.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It didn't say that in the question already, they edited that into the question after the comment.

Comment: How do you read a frequency (other than zero) on "2.5-3VDC"?

Comment: I am putting out a clock signal to trip a relay using adjustable 555 timer circuit.  I need to be able to adjust the output to 64HZ to set my timer.   The output is too low of a voltage for the meter I want to use to read.  I have about 3VDC out of the timer circuit but the meter needs a minimum of 10VDC to read.

Comment: @RussellSmith my point was that VDC means "volts, direct current", or a steady voltage, not an AC signal.

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: You could probably use a comparator with a 12V supply to level shift the signal.